# git pushing to gitlab is extremely slow

Tags: git

my git pushes are very slow, it takes me like 45 minutes to push a 200MB project to gitlab, I get 70.00 KiB/s  on average, any idea why this is happening?

I'm trying to use --verbose switch to see if I can see what files are slowing it down (generally after 1/% it goes A BIT faster... but --verbose switch doesn't show any additional info, is there something like this?

I usually git push via ssh.

Could this be because I have a few images in my project?  like 8MB worth of images shouldn't make it THAT slow...

Anyway, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

## Yes it's the images.

**Adding images to a git repo is a known issue for making a repo much slower to push and pull.**

The reason is that for the size of one image is equivalent to thousands of lines of text files. Add 3-4 images and you're massively increasing the size of your repo.

### What to do?

Three practical approaches

#### 1. Accept things as they are.

Know for next time to avoid putting images in a git repo.
Where to put them, on an external service for images; often Amazon S3 or use a content delivery network (like Cloudinary which has a free plan).

The good news is that the slowness should only be the first time images are pushed/pulled to a new location. After that.. pushes/pull's will only bring down the diffs which will usually be text files again.

So this means setting up this repo will always be slow now, but once pulled down should be fine again.

#### 2. Wind things back to as they were.

To keep your repository fast and small like it used to be, you're going to want to take the images back out.  Doing that with git is going to be fiddly as git's whole design premis is that its hard for devs to scrub committed files from the repo.

#### 3. Start over.. go nuclear on your git history and start over.

This is usually totally not recommend as you loose all your commit history, but if you're a newer dev and this is a very small project.. then practically yeah you could start over. Removing the git folder, remove the images, implement the images by referring to an external url and then commit the rest of the files back into your new repo.

Proceed with caution if you're going this way.

Comment: That's nonesense...Yes, pushing images to a repo can make it slow, especially when the images change often. But a total of 200MB should just be able to reach a nice speed.

Comment: Depends where in the world you live. With only text files, git pulling/pushing is fairly snappy everywhere. Once images have been saved into the repo, a delay is usually expected as you suddenly are downloading larger assets when you pull/push. Once a new asset is pulled onto your computer it should be fast again. But on a big team, you're making everyone on the team face this delay when they first pull down larger files. Hundreds of text files are much smaller than even one image usually.